# Is it possible to change the innerHtml of another page (html file) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

What I am trying to do is to create a set of `[FR,EN]` buttons, corresponding to languages.

I´m expecting to change the innerHtml of certain `<div>` or `<span>` to the right language in every Html file I have, when clicking on one of them.

> Ex: If I click on `fr` =>  `Hello` will become `Bonjour`

I can make it work when the button is on the same page, but I would like the change to be applied on all of my documents.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Store the language selected in a cookie or in localStorage. Then run the same code on each page based on stored value

Comment: you can only affect what's in the currently loaded page using JavaScript. So as mentioned above, have a reference to the same code on each page (e.g. link to the same JS file) which can then alter the current page to display the correct language.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot I'll try do to that immediately

Comment: Adding to @charlietfl's answer, you could also store that data server-side in their session-tracking server-side cookie. And based on the session value, send the appropriate contents when the page is loaded.

Comment: It work ! Thanks everybody